# Call c# method from c++ wrap

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, wrapper

I have a c# library with this function:

```
public static int myGetStrings(String sOne, out String sTemp1, out String sTemp2)
{
    sTemp1 = sOne+"1";
    sTemp2 = sOne+"2";
    return 0;
}
```

My c++ wrapper call c# library:

```
char sOneCall[256],sTemp1Call[256],sTemp2Call[256];
sprintf(sOneCall,"this is a test");

int iReturnData = myLibraryClass-> myGetStrings(
    Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr) (char *)sOneCall), 
    Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr) (char *)sTemp1Call),
    Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr) (char *)sTemp2Call) );
```

But when I execute my code the variables "sTemp1Call" and "sTemp1Call" are void.
Why? What is my problem? Where i wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using c++/cli. if so there is no need to use marshal you can just pass a string directly.

```
String ^sOneCall = "this is a test";
String ^sTemp1Call = "";
String ^sTemp2Call = ""


int iReturnData = myLibraryClass-> myGetStrings(sOneCall,sTemp1Call,sTemp2Call);
```

Your function has out parameters if you want to get the values after the call you will need to keep around the .net object a PtrToStringAnsi copies the strings to a new String^ object so you will need to copy it back to your native ptr.